# I need some help shortening this regular expression

Tags: regex

I currently try to get into regular expressions for school and have to work on the task to shorten this regular expression:

```
r = 0(e + 0 + 1)* + (e + 1)(1 + 0)* + e
```

with e being the empty word epsilon.

So far I got to this:

```
r = 0(0 + 1)* + 1(1 + 0)* + e
```

considering the rule

```
r* = (e + r)*
```

However, I don't really know how to continue. If it wasn't for the kleene star operators, I could use the distributive law, but that won't apply here. I can't really figure out a suitable law to continue on with this regex.

Any helpful tips?

Edit:

I think I got one step further by forming r to

```
r = 0(1 + 0)* + 1(1 + 0)* + e
```

and then being able to combine it to

```
r = (0 + 1)(0 + 1)* + e
```

Is that correct?

Also, we could then say

```
r = (0+1)*
```

which should be the final form

Comment: So, the '+' sign means 'or' in every case, right? Your language consists of strings of 1s and 0s?

Comment: Your answer seems correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that your own deduction is correct except for one thing. Taking your original

```
r = 0(e + 0 + 1)* + (e + 1)(1 + 0)* + e
```

removing e which according to you is empty, leaves

```
r = 0(0 + 1)* + 1(1 + 0)*
```

or in plain words `0 followed by any number of 0 or 1` **or** `1 followed by any number of 1 or 0`.
So the left side states that there has to be at least a `0` and the right side that there has to be a `1`. That means that there must be at least a `0` or a `1`. Now, your flavor of regex is one I've never seen so I don't know how to express `one or more` in your flavor (it's normally a `+`) so I'll express it in *regular* regex, which would be

```
r = [01]+
```

which simply means **`at least one`**`0 or 1 repeated any number of times`.

Regards.